# source binding not working windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

am showing list of movie  as a panorama for my windows phone 7 app. on click on each movie am showing the movie details,cast.
the movie details , cast am showing as a pivot control. movie details works fine
But when i got to show cast as , it doesnt work. i have list of cast objects. and am binding the source to a listbox in the cast pivot control , but it doesnt show any data. Please help me. below are the classes i have used. Thank you

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> MovieItems { get; set; }

 }
```

ItemViewModel.cs

```
 public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

     private string _title;
     public string _Title
      {
        get { return _title; }

        set
        {
            if (value != _title)
            {
                _title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("title");
            }
        }
    }


      private ObservableCollection<Cast> _cast;

    public ObservableCollection<Cast> _Cast
    {
        get { return _cast; }

        set
        {
            if (value != _cast)
            {
                _cast = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Cast");
            }
        }
    }
  ..........

}
```

Cast.cs

```
public class Cast
 {
      public string name { get; set; }
      public string imagesource { get; set; }


      public Cast(string _name, string _imagesource)
      {
        this.imagesource = _imagesource;
        this.name = _name;
      }
 }
for each movie i have a list of cast objects
```

MovieModel.cs

```
                  App.Model.MovieItems.Add(
                   new ItemViewModel()
                   {
                       _Title = data["title"].ToString(),
                       _Cast=casObs,
                      ........
                   }
                   );
```

moviedetails.xaml

```
               <ListBox Name="ListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding _Cast}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                            <Canvas>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="120,5,60,3" Text="{Binding name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="32" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                                <Image Height="90" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,10,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Source="{Binding imagesource}" />
                            </Canvas>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("title");
```

to

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("_Title");
```

And

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("Cast");
```

to

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("_Cast");
```

Hope it's help.

Comment: sorry guys it my fault. i was clearing the cast objects from the ObservableCollection and thats why it was not working.

Comment: ok, but what about my answer (it works with NotifyPropertyChanged("title"); or NotifyPropertyChanged("_Title"); )?

Answer (score 0):

apply converter inbetween, where you need to return ImageSource/BitmapImage, instead of string